# Clickhouse shared dictionaries

Tags: columnstore, clickhouse

Is there any way to "share" or "replicate" a dictionary among multiple machine in the same shared and/or cluster using clickhouse.

Currently I have ~10 files for external dictionaries that clickhouse loads up (and a few csvs where the data is loaded from). All the dictionaries are quite small and critical for a lot of queries, so I'd like to find a way to distribute them instead of having to maintain up to date copies on every cluster.

Is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try use configuration managament tools like a puppet, ansible for rollup your dictionaries over multiple nodes together clickhouse configs

or just use rsync or NFS share and run **service clickhouse reload**  as neccessary

Comment: Custom scripts with rsync is probably what I'm going for.

Comment: NFS share seems icky because if the server sharing the drive fails all the others will loss all dictionaries. \